gnu make parallel jobs for groups but sequential inside a group
I am big fan of "makei -j" but I am looking for a solution in this scenario. I want the parallel jobs for groups(say different make targets) but (if a group is aliased to many sub-targets) it should be sequential within the group.
(Similar topic was discussed in Order of "order-only" prerequisites not kept in a multithreaded makefile but it did not work).
Let us take the simplified example as below.
== Makefile ==
t0:
    echo t0_start `date` 
    sleep 5
    echo t0_end `date` 

t1:
    echo t1_start `date`
    sleep 5
    echo t1_end `date` 

t2:
    echo t2_start `date`
    sleep 5
    echo t2_end `date` 

# The above were delivered from another team

grp_t0 : t0

grp_t1_t2: t1 t2

all:  grp_t0 | grp_t1_t2

==

grp_t0 and grp_t1_t2 are defined by the consumer team. How do I now run grp_t0 and grp_t1_t2 in parallel but sequential inside grp_t1_t2.

The above code produced
==
t0_start Sun Apr 7 08:31:59 PDT 2024
t2_start Sun Apr 7 08:31:59 PDT 2024
t1_start Sun Apr 7 08:31:59 PDT 2024
t0_end Sun Apr 7 08:32:04 PDT 2024
t2_end Sun Apr 7 08:32:04 PDT 2024
t1_end Sun Apr 7 08:32:04 PDT 2024
==

The expectation is to start {t0,t1} in parallel and t2 after that

Yes, order-only has nothing to do with parallel builds, and it has nothing to do with the relative order of prerequisite building.  What foo: bar | baz means is that make will ensure that both bar and baz are up to date using the normal make processing, but when deciding whether foo is up to date or not only the modification time of bar, and not baz, will be considered.  baz is "order-only" in that it is guaranteed to be built (ordered) before foo, but it is not considered for foo's up-to-date condition.

Why do you want this? More specifically, why do you want less parallelism than is actually afforded by the dependencies among your targets?  I ask because it sounds like you may be trying to to implement a workaround for not specifying all of your targets' prerequisites, which would be a hack-job of a solution for a problem you needlessly created yourself.

@JohnBollinger, You can treat it like many independent teams but we want to ensure the order within the team, for example. build-of-src followed by compile and then to burn the flash.

I'm not tracking here.  How does specifying prerequisites appropriately not already provide for correct build order within each group? Parallel or not, make does not build any target before all its out-of-date prerequisites have been built.  Why is that insufficient?

@JohnBollinger, I tried to create an example for general discussion. In my case, though it can be run in parallel within a group, the integrator wanted to have a choice to make it sequential. I agree it is not normal but thats what I face.

Use .NOTPARALLEL:
.NOTPARALLEL: grp_t1_t2
grp_t1_t2: t1 t2

Or .WAIT:
grp_t1_t2: t1 .WAIT t2

Both options require Make 4.4 or newer. .NOTPARALLEL has existed before, but it didn't accept individual targets.

My understanding of the OP is that they want .NOTPARALLEL: t1 t2.

The .WAIT option will work but just to be clear, if there is some OTHER target which depends on these grp_* targets, or their prerequisites, in addition to all, which make is considering then these could still be run in parallel.  In other words, the .WAIT only is in effect for this specific target.

@RenaudPacalet Nope. This syntax would make more, but it doesn't work this way: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel-Disable.html

@HolyBlackCat Oops, sorry, I meant .NOTPARALLEL: grp_t1_t2. My understanding is that they just want t1and t2 to be serialized.

@RenaudPacalet Ah, right, fixed.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions. Since both the features .NOTPARALLEL and .WAIT needs newer version of the Make, let me take it with my unix admin. However, I found a possible solution using $(MAKE). Let me add it as answer

@KannanRamaswamy You can build newer make from source, it shouldn't be hard.

t0:
    echo t0_start `date` 
    sleep 5
    echo t0_end `date` 

t1:
    echo t1_start `date`
    sleep 5
    echo t1_end `date` 

t2:
    echo t2_start `date`
    sleep 5
    echo t2_end `date` 

# The above were delivered from another team

t0_completed:
    $(MAKE) t0

t1_completed:
    $(MAKE) t1

t2_completed: t1_completed
    $(MAKE) t2

grp_t0 : t0_completed

grp_t1_t2 : t1_completed t2_completed

all: grp_t0 grp_t1_t2


UNIX: make -s all -j
t0_start Tue Apr 9 06:47:10 PDT 2024
t1_start Tue Apr 9 06:47:10 PDT 2024
t0_end Tue Apr 9 06:47:15 PDT 2024
t1_end Tue Apr 9 06:47:15 PDT 2024
t2_start Tue Apr 9 06:47:15 PDT 2024
t2_end Tue Apr 9 06:47:20 PDT 2024

It seems like it has done the job. Do I miss something?

I'm not following why you introduce the *_completed targets instead of just making t1 a prerequisite of t2.

@JohnBollinger, the target definition for "t2" comes from another team and I have to use via "include". So I cannot change their file. I created dummy "*_completed" to add needed prerequisite of my choice.

This question seems full of unspecified requirements.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I am not sure what is to be added. If this is not helping the community, shall I delete my post?
